# Working with multiple interface and single common field in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, interface, components, mode

I have 2 different components,component A uses model A and component B uses model B. Now A has an id and component B should be using that id to process its method. So if I want that same id in Model B, is that possible?

```
Model A
export interface A{ id: number,firstname: string, lastname: string}
Model B
export interface B {id: number, phone: number}
```

Or is it possible to add 'phone' to Model A as below?

```
export interface A{ id: number,firstname: string, lastname: string,phone: number}
```

But I get error as when it is called in the component A , phone is not used.
What is the best way or practical way to fix this?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Your interfaces don't limit the value of `id`. They are just numbers. If they're the same number, that's ok. I'm unclear as to what you're asking...

Comment: Could you show us the exact error you got?

Comment: Make phone with ? optional.

Comment: @derstauner so make everything optional except ID? as comp A would use some and comp B rest, only id is common?

Comment: it looks like you want to use a "Person" interface to be be sure people use th propoer object. if you want to bee sure to have a a phone in both, maybe you could just build one interface ? export interface Person implements A, B ? and use it in both ? or is your compoent extending the interface itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only the `phone`, you can add it to Model A like this:

```
export interface A{ id: number,firstname: string, lastname: string, phone?: number}
```

The question mark makes this field optional, so you can add a phone, but you don't need.

But I think the follow way is the best in your case, structured like you would in a database.

```
Model A
export interface A{ id: number,firstname: string, lastname: string, modelB?: B}
Model B
export interface B {id: number, phone: number}
```

Here we set the complete `interface B` as a child of A, so to say. These are the best ways and the best practice.
By the way: Yes, you can "change" types and interfaces with typescript (add new property, remove one) but this is not a good thing... We build interfaces to structure our data for simple reusing and type safety. If we change interfaces - we doesn't need it; that's my opinion.